# QuillJS : Customize attr alt

Tags: quill

Thank you for your interest in my question.

**Technology used :** PHP / JS

**Wish result :** I would like to allow the possibility to add the attribute "alt" to the images.
When adding an image, it is sent to the server, then the img tag with url (src) is inserted into the editor.
It works perfectly.

What I want is when you click on an image in the editor we have a box that opens

The box proposes to customize the attribute "alt" a bit like customizing links in quilljs.

**See image :**

[image]

**Question :** Someone would have come across this stuff, if not what approach should I take?
Would anyone have an idea of how I should go about it?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions in one post. This should be split into two independent questions. It will be easier to answer and discuss each issues separately.

Comment: Thank you for these clarifications, I would be careful for next time!
For these questions already send, do you think I have to delete and then create two new questions or will it pass for this time?

Comment: It would be sufficient if you just cut second question and paste it into new one. When you do I will take a look at them. Maybe I Wil be able to help

Comment: Very good idea, that's done! I'm new here, your advice is precious!

Answer (score 4):

i did something like this.
Firstly, i create my own **image blot**

```
class CustomImage extends BlockEmbed {
  static create (value) {
    let node = super.create()
    let img = document.createElement('img')
    img.setAttribute('alt', value.alt || '')
    img.setAttribute('src', value.url)
    node.appendChild(img)
    return node
  }
static formats (node) {
    let format = {}
    // do something with format for example format.alt = node.setAttribute('alt')
    // it's need to save changes in Delta
    return format
}
// also need to define static value
static value (node) {
    return {
      alt: node.getAttribute('alt'),
      url: node.getAttribute('src')
    }
  }
// and "public" typical method in JS
format (name, value) {
  if (name === 'alt') {
    this.domNode.alt = value
  }
}
```

Second thing, i create simple popup settings for images (it's just **html** element) and put it document.

And then I peeped in quill modules (quill-image-drop-module) how it implements in right way. I just handle click on document and if click was fired on **img** element i show popup to user.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'IMG') {
    // just open popup and pass to it all settings from your blot image
    // for get all props from image use let blot = Parchment.find(e.target)
    // read more about this below
  }
}
```

To get all properties from your image and change them, just use **blot** object. It's need for normal work with history (CTRL+Z). Don't change the image **DOM** element directly, use blot. So, to get all properties and work with them, use this:

```js
import Parchment from 'parchment'
let blot = Parchment.find(this.currentImg)
// blot contain all what you need, all properties
// and you can change them in this way:
blot.format('alt', e.target.value)
```

I hope it'll be helpful for you. It's just basic implement, but i guess, that you understand what to do next, and how it works.

P.S. I don't sure, that is the most right way, but i did it like this.
Thank you.

Comment: Perfect !
This is a very good start.

I understand the idea but I am lost at the blot.
Extends "BlockEmbed"?
I must also import "Parchment"?

I understand the principle but can not apply it :)

Comment: I use `Parchment` only for its static method `find` because it allows finding "quill entity" that stored in DOM element.

This method is described here: https://github.com/quilljs/parchment/blob/master/src/registry.ts#L59

In fact, it just returns result of this operation: 
   
node['__blot'].blot    

`node` - is just DOM element.   

It's kinda internal store for quill entity in your DOM element. Afret that, you can proccess returned `blot` (quill entity) and invoke any method of blot. For example `format`